# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to parse a large xml file (~500 MB) with python `lxml` library, the `iterparse`, using:

```
context = etree.iterparse('large-file.xml')
for event, element in context:
    # do some stuff 
    element.clear()
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 176, in <module> test_parser()
  File "test.py", line 121, in test_parser
    for event, element in context:
  File "src/lxml/iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml/etree.c:155963)
  File "src/lxml/iterparse.pxi", line 193, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml/etree.c:155671)
  File "src/lxml/iterparse.pxi", line 228, in lxml.etree.iterparse._read_more_events (src/lxml/etree.c:156298)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1362, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.feed (src/lxml/etree.c:116552)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 589, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResult (src/lxml/etree.c:107619)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 598, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/etree.c:107738)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 709, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/etree.c:109447)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 638, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/etree.c:108301)
  File "large-file.xml", line 20593
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup, line 20593, column 199
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python lxml.etree for huge XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850345/using-python-lxml-etree-for-huge-xml-files)

Comment: It is a bit different, since here I used `iterparse`. But using the solution there I could resolve my issue by `context = etree.iterparse('large-file.xml', huge_tree=True)`