# breaking the lxml.etree.HTML.xpath max parsing depth limit

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

The HTML xpath parser from lxml.etree seems to have max depth limit. It won't traverse further to parse the text if the depth exceeds 254. Here's a python code snippet demonstrating this:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

# Setup HTML tabs
x = "<span>"
x_ = "</span>"

# Set recursion depth to 255
depth = 255 

# Construct and parse using lxml.etree.HTML
# This gives an empty list []
print(etree.HTML(x * depth + "<p>text to be extracted</p >" + x_* depth).xpath("//p//text()"))

# Set the recursion depth to 254
depth = 254

# This gives the correct result ['text to be extracted']
print(etree.HTML(x * depth + "<p>text to be extracted</p >" + x_* depth).xpath("//p//text()"))
```

In some use cases, we will encounter large text files which recursion depth is larger than 254, then the lxml parser will fail to provide the desired text. How could we break the limit to let it parse beyond 254 recursions?

[XSLT](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XSLT-class.html) document provides a static method called `set_global_max_depth` which enables the user to customize the max depth it could traverse, is there any similar method provided in lxml.etree.HTML?

[This mail post](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xslt/2010-November/msg00008.html) discusses the traversing depth of XSLT and might be helpful.

Comment: Years later, I know... sorry but were you actually able to fix this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse with a custom [`HTMLParser`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.HTMLParser-class.html) instance where `huge_tree` is set to `True`. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850345/using-python-lxml-etree-for-huge-xml-files) for the XML case. (This has nothing to do with XPath by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

**1.** Instead of `lxml`, use `xml.etree.ElementTree`, which doesn't have the same XPATH depth limitation:

***Code:***

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


# Setup HTML tabs
x = "<span>"
x_ = "</span>"

# Set recursion depth
depth = 300

xml_text = f'{x * depth}<p>text to be extracted</p >{x_ * depth}'

root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
print(root.find(".//p").text)
```

***Output:***

```
text to be extracted
```

**2.** Python's `ElementTree` doesn't support the entire XPATH specification.  So if you have complex XPATH queries that won't run using `ElementTree`, you could use [Pawpaw](https://github.com/rlayers/pawpaw).  Pawpaw has a robust query language called Plumule, which you can use instead of (or parallel to) `ElementTree`'s XPATH:

***Code:***

```py
import sys
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from pawpaw import xml


# Setup HTML tabs
x = "<span>"
x_ = "</span>"

# Set recursion depth to 255
depth = 300

xml_text = f'{x * depth}<p>text to be extracted</p >{x_ * depth}'

root = ET.fromstring(xml_text, parser=xml.XmlParser())
node = root.ito.find('**[d:element]{*[d:start_tag]/**[d:name]&[s:p]}/*[d:text]')
print(str(node))
```

***Output:***

```
text to be extracted
```