# Python lxml XPathEvalError: Error in xpath expression when parsing larger file

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The following XPATH query works with the majority of the XML files I am parsing, but it is causing an `XPathEvalError` on a larger XML file (~200MB) that I am attempting to parse.

```
from lxml import etree


query = "//*[self::foo or self::bar]/test/entry"

# Working with a 1 MB file
small_tree = etree.parse("http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/courses/wsu.xml")
_ = small_tree.xpath(query)

# Failing with a 683 MB file
big_tree = etree.parse("http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/pir/psd7003.xml")
_ = big_tree.xpath(query)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-495ebeb2207b>", line 1, in <module>
    big_tree.xpath("//*[self::foo or self::bar]/test/entry")

  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2287, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath

  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 359, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__

  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result

XPathEvalError: Error in xpath expression
```

Is this a bug with lxml?

For testing purposes, you can use this sample small XML file to see the query work () and this sample large XML file to see the query fail.

Comment: Mind if you can share a part of the XML please? I get that you're trying to look for a branch called `self` but some context would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @jayg_code - you can replicate this error using any large file. See my updated example code which now includes sample XML data.

Comment: Perhaps `huge_tree=True` helps. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850445/407651.

Comment: `huge_tree` doesn't help. Problem confirmed to occur with Python 3.8 64bit on Windows (with and without `huge_tree`). I'd say it is a bug. However, the working set for Python.exe is around 8GB after loading `big_tree` - a 32bit-Python couldn't even load that file. So, loading a DOM of such a big XML file into memory is not really efficient. I would suggest to use a SAX API  to process XML files that big.